# Erro ao tentar cadastrar

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

Boa Tarde, no momento em que tento registrar no formulario, eu programo na linguagem c# com asp.net, razor e NHibernate.

Esse é meu DAO

```
public IList<Rota> Comparacao()
        {
        //*string hql = "Select p from Rota p";
        string hql = "SELECT Id, DtLancamento, Km_Atual, Combustivel, NVeiculoId, (SELECT TOP 1 x.Km_Atual FROM Rota x WHERE x.NVeiculoId  = r.NVeiculoId AND x.Id != r.Id AND x.DtLancamento < r.DtLancamento Order By x.DtLancamento desc, x.Id desc) as Km_Anterior FROM Rota r";
        IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Rota>();
        }
```

Meu Controller

```
dao.Comparacao();
            if (viewModel.Km_Atual < p.Km_Atual)
                    {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
                    "Km Atual precisa ser maior que o atual");
                    }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                    Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota();
                    dao.Adicionar(rota);
                    //return View();
                    return RedirectToAction("Form");
                    }
                else
                    {
                    ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDao.Lista();
                    return View("Index", viewModel);
                    }
                }
```

Meu Model

```
public class Rota
        {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DtLancamento { get; set; }
        public virtual int Km_Atual { get; set; }
        public virtual int Km_Anterior { get; set; }
        public virtual float Combustivel { get; set; }
        public virtual Veiculo NVeiculo { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Minha ViewModel

```
public class RotaModel
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtLancamento { get; set; }
    public int Km_Atual { get; set; }
    public int Km_Anterior { get; set; }
    public float Combustivel { get; set; }
    public int NVeiculoId { get; set; }

    public Rota CriaRota()
        {
        Rota rota = new Rota()
        {
            Id = this.Id,
            DtLancamento = this.DtLancamento,
            Km_Atual = this.Km_Atual,
            Km_Anterior = this.Km_Anterior,
            Combustivel = this.Combustivel
        };

        if (this.NVeiculoId != 0)
        {
            Veiculo ncarro = new Veiculo()
        {
            Id = this.NVeiculoId
        };
            rota.NVeiculo = ncarro;
        }
        return rota;
        }

    public RotaModel(Rota p)
        {
        this.Id = p.Id;
        this.DtLancamento = p.DtLancamento;
        this.Km_Atual = p.Km_Atual;
        this.Km_Anterior = p.Km_Anterior;
        this.Combustivel = p.Combustivel;
        if (p.NVeiculo != null)
            {
            this.NVeiculoId = p.NVeiculo.Id;
            }
        }
    public RotaModel()
    {
    //* Construtor vazio, sempre necessario!! <-- Importante.    
    }
    }
}
```

O erro que aparece quando tento cadastra é esse:
***O valor "System.Object[]" não é do tipo "BlogWeb.Models.Rota" e não pode ser usado nesta coleção genérica.***

Comment: O erro já fala qual é o problema.

Comment: Sou iniciante no c#, mas como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Só para ter certeza, qual a linha do erro?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `viewModel` no controller?

Comment: Ele consta na linha return do DAO - "return query.List<Rota>();"

Comment: Coloquei a minha viewmodel na pergunta pra caso facilitar

Comment: Acredito que a solução é que vc tenha que transformar o valor para a classe Rota. `TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Rota>())`

Comment: Coloco isso na linha do return né?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente transformar as colunas para a classe `Rota` usando o [Transform](http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/06/19/queryover-series-part-4-transforming/) do *nhibernate*, desta maneira:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(hql).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Rota>());
```